# SQL Select Top and Random Fill

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to select and insert the top 4650 fields from table a column g into table b column e. How can I randomly fill this column with data from table a column g? How do I replace the data that already exist in column e? Would this be easier to do in multiple parts?

Comment: (1) What database do you use?  (2) Do you want the values filled in randomly or do you want the top fields by some criteria?

Comment: is there any relationship between the two tables?

Comment: First remove all the values that are in the table b cole. then try to insert the values that are in the table a colg.

Comment: I am using an sql database. I would like the values filled randomly form table a. The problem I have is I have 4650 products and over 60k orders. I am trying to make some fake data and would like these  products to randomly fill the field.

Comment: @David Do you need all 60k orders to have a randomly assigned product id or do you only want 4650 orders with each a random, different product id?

Comment: I would like them all to have one of the 4650 product id's I do not care how they are dispersed just that I can fill the column with this same data. It would be nice if it was random but if I can just fill it again and again until it is full that is fine too.

Comment: SELECT * FROM ORDERS_TABLE INNER JOIN PRODUCTS_TABLE ON 1=1 will essentially give you a cross join. If the select looks good enuff for your "random data generation" then just convert it to an update for the order table.

Comment: @David Do these tables have auto-incrementing int PK's? Is column g the PK? Is column e a FK? This may go faster if you flesh out your question a little more.

Comment: @TMNT2014 cross join gives him 4650 * 60k rows, how is he supposed to use that to fill up his 60k orders?

Comment: @Guillaume If you convert it into an update it would only update the 60K rows in your order table.

Comment: @David would it be possible for you to share the table structures?

Answer (score 1):

if this is just for a single column then this should work for you.

```
insert into tableB (columnE)
select top(4650) columnG from tableA
```

if there is a relationship between the tables then you could do something like this

```
Update x
set columnE = y.columnG 
from tableB as x
inner join (select top(4650) ID from tableA) as y
on x.ID = y.ID
```

you could also utilize CTE

```
;with as 
(
   select top (4650) id,ColumnG 
   from TableA
) Y

update X
set columnE = Y.ColumnG
from TableB as X
inner join Y on x.ID = y.ID
```

We will need the structure of the tables to fully answer your question

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes 2 things: A) your Products table has an unbroken auto-incrementing Id column (by unbroken I mean no deleted rows that would cause the int to jump) and b) your Orders has an int PK Id column

```
DECLARE @MaxProductId int
SELECT @MaxProductId = MAX(Id) FROM Product

SELECT p.Description, o.Id
FROM Product p
JOIN Order o
    ON p.Id = o.Id % @MaxProductId
```

This will haphazardly join a product to an order. If you like what you see, you can change the p's column to whatever your g column is. You can then use UPDATE and this select to join on your Order's Id.

Answer (score 0):

Well I actually went about this completely different. I made a temp table with 2 fields, Temp1, Temp2. I pulled all the Products and put them in Temp1 then used Two different updates. One to add random digits to Temp2 and one to change my TableToUpdate to those temp digits. This way I can do this to other tables and the data looks different but keeps the sales forecasting structure.

UPDATE TempTable
SET   [Temp2] = abs(checksum(NewId())) % 5000 + 10000

UPDATE TableToUpdate
SET Product = ( SELECT Temp2 
                         FROM TempTable
                         WHERE TableToUpdate.Product = TempTable.Temp1)

Thank you everyone for your input.